# Saving WebView URL

Tags: android, webview, sharedpreferences

I've been trying literally everything I can find on this. I'm currently using an alert dialog with an edittext to add URL's to my webview. All of that works fine. What I'm trying to do is save the URL that's entered so when the app is closed and started again, it'll open on that same URL. I've tried basically every different way of using either SharePreferences or writing to a file and still can't figure it out. Pretty frustrating now especially considering the fact that its probably something stupid that I'm not realizing. Lol.

This is just the set up for the dialog with the webview. The webview is also being called earlier in the code.

```
//Popup Window
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        String url = input.getText().toString();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Enter Dynmap URL");
        alertDialog.setView(input);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                GETTEXT = input.getText().toString();

                Browser.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
                Browser.loadUrl(input.getText().toString());


            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show how you are storing and reading data back from the sharedpreferences or file system, as the current code you have posted doesnt make us understand how you are saving the system.

Comment: *facepalm* Just realized that.